# PDP-11 pure executable - version 16

Tags: disassembly, assembly

PDP-11 pure executable reverse engineering:

1. Dont have access to Ida pro. Ollydbg, Immunity doesnt open it.
2. `radare2` with MIPS, a lots of errors.
3. `file`:

   ```
   # file lightning-tp.b  
   lightning-tp.b: PDP-11 pure executable - version 16
   ```
4. `strings`:

   ```
   # strings -a lightning-tp.b  
   /* tp pulse
    [#wan | lan1 | lan2 | lan3 | lan4]             ... test port
    [#waveform | m-jitter | s-jitter | distortion] ... test mode  */
   ```

Question: How to run PDP-11 executable ?

Answer (score 3):

You might find interesting help [here](http://www.pdp11.org/). There are many emulators and can even find a PDP-11 to buy.

Answer (score 2):

You can find many PdP-11 emulators on Internet...

For example, you can use [SIMH](http://simh.trailing-edge.com/) which is open source and available as a package on Debian.

Answer (score 1):

r2 is starting to support pdp11 now, you can give it a try,